# How to handle errors with logstash?

Tags: logstash, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, logstash-configuration

I just a have a question about error handling in Logstash.

For example I have a cluster like;

kafka -> logstash -> Elasticsearch

and this logstash is also connected to a HDFS.

so either

**kafka -> logstash -> Elasticsearch**
or
**kafka -> logstash -> HDFS**
(by the way i am consuming from two different topics)

my question is here; how can i stop consuming from the topic of HDFS in Kafka if HDFS is not reachable and same for topic of elasticsearch?

I am sure that if I use Spark Streaming instead of logstash there is a system of error handling which will enable me to do so but I dont know at all how it can be done via Logstash. Can you please give me some information about that ?

Thank you all

Comment: If logstash is unable to write to the output, it will stop reading from the input.  Did you need more than that?

Comment: I think that might be enough. What happens if Kafka topic goes down ?

Comment: Can't help with kafka; sorry.